# Application Insights - Visualize Analytics query with scatter chart

Tags: azure-application-insights, power-automate

Is there anyway of getting the Scatter chart as the output of Visualize Analytics query connector in Microsoft flow?

I tried using the custom value but not sure what is the custom value needed for scatter charts.

Thanks,Shridhar

Update

> Connector - Visualize Analytics query

Query

```
let today = now();
let selectedDuration = totimespan(1d);
requests 
| where timestamp  between((today -selectedDuration)  .. today)
| project resultCode = strcat((toint(resultCode) /100) , 'XX') 
| order by resultCode 
| summarize ["Http response code"] = count() by resultCode
//| render scatterchart //don't need this for the connector
```

Comment: need more info to be helpful.  what kind of query/etc, what connectors are you using, what are you using to generate the chart, etc?

Comment: I want to query application insight using MS flow. Updated the question with relevant details.